# Does dispatch_group_wait allow cutting in line?

Tags: ios, macos, grand-central-dispatch

This question is about Grand Central Dispatch, and `dispatch_group_wait()` in particular.

Assume a `dispatch_group` called `group` with 10 tasks in it waiting to be performed.

Elsewhere I have a task that needs to wait for any tasks in `group` to finish before it executes. To make that happen, I use `dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)`.

To distinguish it from the tasks in `group` I'll call it `lonelyTask`.

If another task gets added to `group` while `lonelyTask` is waiting, which gets executed first, `lonelyTask` or the task that was added to `group`? In other words, do tasks added to a `group` while another task is waiting to execute get to "cut in line" ahead of the waiting task, or is the order in which they were called maintained?

I have searched the documentation, but haven't been able to find an answer to this question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group is a +/- counter (semaphore) that fires each time it reaches zero. It is unaware of tasks, because dispatch_group_async() is just a wrapper that enter()s group before task submission and enqueues a new block that will call task's block and then leave() that group. That's all. Groups may be even used without queues as asynchronous retain-counters or sml that.

So in general "you can't".

But if you are able to [re]target (dispatch_set_target_queue()) all related queues to a single concurrent queue, then dispatch_barrier_async() on that queue may do what you want, if called in proper isolation. Note that group has nothing to do with this at all.

Also, original lonelyTask is not a task from group's point of view — it is unrelated thread of execution that waits until group is balanced. The synonym for "cutting in line" is a "barrier".

---

Another approach would be to create a private group for each taskset and wait for that specific group. That will not insert a barrier though — following tasks will not wait for completion of lonelyTask and any uncontrolled async()s may "break the rules", leading to funny debugging sessions.

Answer (score 3):

`dispatch_group_wait` and `dispatch_group_notify` both wait for the number of items that have entered the group to transition to zero. So, if you add an eleventh task to the group before all of the original ten tasks complete, a call to `dispatch_group_wait` will wait for all eleven to complete before continuing.